# Flutter failed assertion: 'has size'

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code that is throwing the error:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Text('yes'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
```

SingleChildScrollView here is the direct child of the Scaffold. The error happens after setting the width of the Container inside the row. I even limited the size of the row using SizedBox but then it throws the error for the column:

[image]

Can someone let me know the cause and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your container width

```
 SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Row(
          children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('yes'),
            ),
           ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I can't set the container width as the media query width as I have other elements to add next to it.

Comment: Wrapping the Container around Expanded and removing the width is working fine. Maybe I'll just go this way

Comment: @dipansh this is also correct I update the my answer